# Fantasy Anime with an overweight father and an inappropriate sister

Tags: story-identification, anime

This was a fantasy anime. The main character's dad is overweight and is always asking him for money. I believe it is more of a comedy.

He also has a sister who has "weird" feelings about him. I recall his father telling him that's not what siblings are supposed to do.

It reminded me of [*The 8th Son? Are You Kidding Me?*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/38830/Hachi-nan_tte_Sore_wa_Nai_deshou)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?

Comment: it was about 6 or so months ago i believe. Or im just a dipshit